# Making a private call in a extended class?

Tags: php, overriding, private

I have a parent class containing a function funcB() which I like to override with a better function by making just a few changes in this function. This function in the parent class makes a call to another private function in the same class.

Sample code:

```
class classA {
  private function funcA() {
    return "funcA called";
  }

  public function funcB() {
    $result = $this->funcA();
    return $result;
  }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA {
  public function funcB($a) {
    //do some more stuff
    $result = $this->funcA();
    return $result;
  }
}
```

I get a Fatal error, because I'm not allowed to make a call to the private parent::funcA() function from within ClassB. But the call must being made. How is this still possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Declare the `private` method as `protected` instead.

[See the documentation about *visibility*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php):

> Class members declared public can be accessed everywhere. Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited and parent classes. Members declared as private may only be accessed by the class that defines the member.

Comment: Thanks! Does this mean ClassA has a faulty design? (I didn't design ClassA you know.)

Comment: @Zac L: Well, it means that initially, `funcA` was not supposed to be called by subclasses *or* that `classA` was not meant to be subclassed. Maybe the original author didn't think about this scenario. I would not say it is *faulty* design.